# how to call other action in play framework

Tags: templates, action, playframework

```
def a = {
  b
}
def b = {
  logger.debug("call ok")
  Template
}
```

When I call method `a` I see the logger output (so `b` is called), but it returns the template of `a`. Why? I want it to return template of method `b`

Comment: Please give more information what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

by Template you mean a "render" command? If so, it should work. If not, please edit the question and post the exact code.